# How to make pipeline component visible in toolbox?

Tags: biztalk

I know the drill - Choose Items - point to the dll - voilà!

But there are some attributes on the pipeline component. Does these affect the visibility? And how to change these?

```
<ComponentCategory(CategoryTypes.CATID_PipelineComponent), _
 ComponentCategory(CategoryTypes.CATID_Any), _
 ComponentCategory(CategoryTypes.CATID_Validate), _
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("E7C186DF-D5DD-46a0-90A4-A2A6804763B0")>
ublic Class clsComponent
    Implements IBaseComponent, Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IComponent, IPersistPropertyBag, IComponentUI
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but according to Microsoft, here is what you need to do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577482(v=bts.20).aspx

All the .NET pipeline component assemblies (native and custom) **must be located in the \Pipeline Components folder to be executed by the server**. If the pipeline with a custom component will be deployed across several servers, the component's binaries must be present in the specified folder on every server.

**You do *not* need to add a custom pipeline component to be used by the BizTalk Runtime to the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).**

Custom COM components in the pipeline will also appear in the Toolbox, provided they are registered on the computer as a COM component. Custom .NET pipeline components must be placed into the \Pipeline Components folder.

After the binary files are in the correct location, you need to add the component to the Toolbox. For instructions on adding the pipeline component to the Toolbox, see How to [Use the Toolbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560943%28v=bts.20%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you familiar with this - things changed in after BizTalk 2006: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26404.biztalk-server-deploying-custom-pipeline-components-in-biztalk-server-2006-and-higher.aspx.  It's really hard to know which articles to trust.

Comment: We GAC our pipeline components.  I was merely stating, at the time, that BizTalk will recognize those components even if they are not GAC'd as long as they are in that folder.  We are using 2013R2 currently, and I believe this holds true in that situation.  Although I do believe that the GAC is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you've written a custom PL component, are trying to add it to your custom PL, have gone to choose from the Choose Items tool box and its not appearing?

These might be obvious but double check that you've performed the following steps;

a) GAC'd the PL Componet Assembly.

b) Copied the PL Component DLL to the **BizTalk Install Location\Pipeline Components** folder.

c) Closed and Re-started your PL Solution.

You should now be able to see your Custom PL Component in the Choose Items Box.

HTH

Comment: I did first two steps but not third one C, restarting VS resolved the issue.